# Cannot find -lgraph error while installing libgraph library on Windows-Subsystem for Linux

Tags: software-installation, windows-subsystem-for-linux

As the title says I'm currently stuck installing libgraph library on Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04 and followed several guides on how to install this library. But I always get the same error:

```
/usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './setbkcolor.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/setbkcolor.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './closegraph.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/closegraph.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getfontcolor.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getfontcolor.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './lineto.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/lineto.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './setcolor.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/setcolor.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './delay.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/delay.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getgraphmode.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getgraphmode.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './setfontcolor.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/setfontcolor.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './detectgraph.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/detectgraph.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getmaxcolor.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getmaxcolor.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './setgraphmode.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/setgraphmode.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './drawpoly.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/drawpoly.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getmaxmode.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getmaxmode.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './textheight.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/textheight.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './ellipse.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/ellipse.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getmaxx.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getmaxx.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './textwidth.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/textwidth.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './fillellipse.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/fillellipse.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getmaxy.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getmaxy.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './moverel.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/moverel.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './fillpoly.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/fillpoly.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getmodename.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getmodename.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './moveto.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/moveto.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './floodfill.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/floodfill.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getmoderange.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getmoderange.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './outtext.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/outtext.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getpixel.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getpixel.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './outtextxy.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/outtextxy.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './graphicstext.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/graphicstext.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './genellipse.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/genellipse.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './setlinestyle.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/setlinestyle.3'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './getlinesettings.3' '/usr/local/man/man3/getlinesettings.3'
test -z "/usr/local/man/man7" || mkdir -p -- . "/usr/local/man/man7"
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './libgraph.7' '/usr/local/man/man7/libgraph.7'
 /usr/bin/install -c -m 644 './grconstants.7' '/usr/local/man/man7/grconstants.7'
make[4]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc/man'
make[3]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[4]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-exec-am'.
make[4]: Nothing to be done for 'install-data-am'.
make[4]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[3]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2/doc'
make[2]: Entering directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2'
Makefile:934: warning: overriding recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
Makefile:409: warning: ignoring old recipe for target 'libgraph.pc'
/bin/bash ./libtool --mode=link gcc -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT -DFONTDIR=\""/usr/local/share/libgraph/Font/"\" -g -O2 -I/usr/include/SDL -D_GNU_SOURCE=1 -D_REENTRANT   -o libguile-libgraph.la -rpath /usr/local/lib -version-info 0:2:0 -export-dynamic -pthread  -lguile -lltdl -lgmp -lcrypt -lm -lltdl   guile-libgraph.lo -lgraph -lm -lSDL_image -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL
gcc -shared  .libs/guile-libgraph.o  -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -pthread -lguile -lgmp -lcrypt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libltdl.so -lgraph -lm -lSDL_image -L/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu -lSDL  -Wl,-soname -Wl,libguile-libgraph.so.0 -o .libs/libguile-libgraph.so.0.0.2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgraph
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [Makefile:379: libguile-libgraph.la] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2'
make[1]: *** [Makefile:552: install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2'
make: *** [Makefile:816: install] Error 2
root@DESKTOP-RF77BCQ:/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2#
root@DESKTOP-RF77BCQ:/mnt/c/C Libraries/libgraph-1.0.2# sudo cp /usr/local/lib/libgraph.* /usr/lib
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I am unfamiliar with libgraph but it seems your problem is that for the linking process of whatever it is that you are building you are assuming libgraph already exists in your libraries directory.

Have you tried using an online tutorial?
https://seitcg.blogspot.com/2015/03/how-to-install-libgraph-on-ubuntu.html
I hope following the steps shown here will solve your issue.

hope this helps!